# How to prevent Ubuntu to start up giving GRUB prompt so that it can show GUI/X window as usual

Tags: boot, grub2

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I press the start/power button,
instead of giving the standard X windows (GUI) it gives me a GRUB prompt: `grub>`

How can I make my computer start normally with Windows? This is the current status after booting (here I tried to look at the content of the disk drive).

[image]

After typing `exit` at the `grub >` prompt.

[image]

GParted:

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85366/discussion-between-pratap-and-scamander).